# Classic ASP: replacing a string

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

The following code:

```
Dim url       
url = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(objFile)
```

gives me

```
C:\KB\Dev\Java.htm
```

Then, when I write it as an href:

```
Response.Write("<a href='" + url + "'>" + objFile.Name + "</a><br>")
```

the link is translated in browser into:

```
file:///C:/KB/Dev/Java/Java.htm
```

whereas I will need it to be

```
file://172.20.4.107/c$/KB/Dev/Java/Java.htm
```

or else, the link won't be valid for navigation.

I was trying:

```
url = Replace(url, "///", "//172.20.4.107/")
url = Replace(url, "c:", "c$")
Response.Write(url & "<br>")
```

but nothing seems to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to replace `///` but these characters are not in your `url` variable. `url` is `C:\KB\Dev\Java.htm`.

Try this instead:

```
url = Replace(url, "\", "/")
url = Replace(url, "C:/", "file://172.20.4.107/c$/")
```

Also keep in mind that it is the end user's *browser* that is converting your `C:\...` path to the `file://...` format. That is not happening in your ASP code.

Comment: This is it! But how come now, when the link seems to be correct, it is not going to this address when I click on it ? :(   And even when I try to "open it in a new tab" I get an "about:blank" page...

Comment: It could be a permissions issue, most likely on the c$ share.

Comment: @dushkin Because browsers see accessing network file shares through hyperlinks as a security risk. i.e - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811570/how-do-i-make-a-file-hyperlink-that-works-in-both-ie-and-firefox Also this might be helpful - [What are the ways to make an html link open a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/q/855614/692942)

Comment: @Lankymart Strange... because if I copy the shortcut of the link and paste it in the address bar - it opens without any problems. Is there a way to overcome this? I will go over your links too...

Comment: @dushkin Not strange if you think about it, no one has control of your URL address bar but hyper-links in a page can come from anywhere. Personally I would assess why you need to access it using this method, could you not map it to the web server then expose it via a virtual directory in IIS for example?

Comment: @Lankymart That is bacause I am totally new to web programming... :-) If you could send me such a tutorial it would be great!

Comment: @dushkin [How to create a virtual directory on an existing Web site to a folder that resides on a remote computer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308150)

Answer (score 3):

What [@Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65775/keith) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35701122/692942) is absolutely fine but you will encounter issue with various degrees in most modern browsers due to hyper linking from local file links being blocked as they're a security risk.

A more robust solution is to not use local file links and negate the risk completely. If you have access to IIS *(If you are using Classic ASP you likely have access to IIS in some form)* you can do this by creating a Virtual Directory that points to your remote computer share and lock down the permissions as you see fit.

Say you set-up a Virtual Directory to point to alias `KB` you could then access it;

```
http://yourhost/KB/dev/java.htm
```

If the Virtual Directory was mapped to

```
\\172.20.4.107\c$\KB\
```

However we can take it a stage further, Admin Shares such as `c$` are not configurable and there for the system to use. To have better control over the mapped directory create a share `KB` for example on the remote computer and set the NTFS permissions as appropriate then point the Virtual Directory to;

```
\\172.20.4.107\KB\
```

You can also call the share `KB$` to hide the share from network browsers.

```
\\172.20.4.107\KB$\
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [How to create a virtual directory on an existing Web site to a folder that resides on a remote computer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308150)